# how to find a address everytime

Tags: visual-c++, memory, int

i have been working on a server and it works with 2 programs i made one is the server and one is the error handler and if the main server fails it restarts it. the 2nd program's main way to handle data is by reading the values from the program(because when i was debugging i was filling in the address's), because writeing the values to a text file would just take too long and also would take up space i really need :| anyway i have about 100,000 values BUT i only need about 100 i need to find ONLY them and if i get the wrong one i'll i might crash it by trying to fix what's "wrong" when nothing is. (sometimes way more but it will not have more then 100k of them by the time i need to know the address's).

i don't need people to tell me how to do someother way to do it, i would really just like to know how to find one value in all of the other ones. and i can't write them to a text file i can only read them from memory because the way i set it up and i don't want to spend 2-3 weeks to recode it.

~*edit*~ 
Sorry, if i was not clear.

i need the address of a value in memory(i.e int, bool and etc), so i can find it.

also i really don't want to share anything with 2 program because if one crashs it might take the other with it. if they are shareing and if it crashs and does not restart then my server will be offline intell someone tells me or i do a update :| so a day or two.

if anyone else is confused sorry and just ask and i'll edit.

Comment: I think you really need to work on clarifying what you're trying to accomplish here. For example, the "100 values all int, in about 100,000 ints" doesn't make any sense, at least to me. Ignoring that, if you want fast communication between programs on the same machine, you might consider pipes or a shared memory region. Pipes are generally simpler.

Comment: Could you please take a moment to edit your question?  It would be easier to understand with a little more punctuation and a few less pronouns ("...to find them in all the other ones."  What is "them?"  What are "the other ones?").  What kind of addresses are these?  IP's?  Mailing addresses?  Pointers?  These details will go a long way towards someone being able to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to find them in memory unless you already know their values.

And if you already know their values, why bother looking them up?

If it'd take you 2-3 weeks to re-code it, you should probably spend those 2-3 weeks rewriting your "server" application so that it's more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it doesn't work that way. Many "values" (variables) are not stored in memory. Instead, they are stored in CPU registers. This is done because registers are a lot faster. However, they are also scarce, so in a big program like yours they will be reused. At different times, different variables will be mapped to a particular register. As a result, even if you know that `localVariable732` is sometimes mapped to the `ECX` register, you won't know whether the `ECX` register currently contains the `localVariable732` value.